# Why angular redirectTo is not working on IIS?

Tags: angular, iis, angular7, angular8

I am new to Angular deployments. So today I tried deploying an angular app to local IIS.
In one scenario, I was able to see the UI.
Scenario 1: Initial route should be navigated to “sample” and SampleComponent is being displayed

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '',  component: SampleComponent},
  { path: 'sample', component: SampleComponent},
  { path : 'dashboard',  component: BillingDashboardComponent, children : [
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'billing-manager' },
    { path: 'billing-manager', component: BillingDashboardSummaryComponent },
  ]},
```

Scenario 2: But when I changed my route to be redirected to “dashboard” which in turn is redirected to ‘billing-summary’. I am seeing a blank screen.

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard' , pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'sample', component: SampleComponent},
  { path : 'dashboard',  component: BillingDashboardComponent, children : [
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'billing-manager' },
    { path: 'billing-runs', component: BillingDashboardSummaryComponent },
  ]},
```

Below is the issue, Can you please help on the issue and explain me what’s causing the issue

[image]

********Edited********
I even added a web.Config file with the below reWrite configs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/billing-manager-dashboard" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This time, 404 error is displayed. Don't know what I'm missing
[image]

Can anyone please help me on this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you look at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/tips-for-running-an-angular-app-in-iis/? I see some differences in the web.config file.

Comment: <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />

Comment: It is displaying a blank page @MikeOne. On reload, 404 page is being displayed

Comment: Does the application of site point to dist folder? Is there a index.html file in dist folder? The error shows that the rewritten url didnot get into angular route. So you need to check how the angular route set.

Comment: I did install the IIS URL Module..When the route is 
`{ path: '', component: SampleComponent}`, it is showing the page.
But when the route is `{ path: '', redirectTo: 'billing-manager' , pathMatch: 'full'}`, then I am facing the issue like no UI is being displayed. I did check the developer tool. It is not loading the component